# Card inside a card

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Creating an app in Flutter for a local resturant/pub/bistro and I want to display a card above all other cards in the menu to show temporary messages/deals. My implementation relies on a menu_screen and a "handler" of sorts (not fully developed mind you).

But there's two problems

1. It displays as a card within a card
2. the information is displayed twice when it should only be shown once at the top of the screen

Here's what it looks like when run on a device for testing:
[image: Here's what it looks like when run on a device for testing]

Pastebin for menu_screen: [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/YTBgc8zg)

```
//  sets up the menu screen for our program
 
//  imports
 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:elehouseapp/handlers/food_menu_handler.dart';
 
//  set up class
class Menus extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: TabBar(
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            indicatorColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: 'Food',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Drink',
              ),
            ]
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            FoodHandler(),
            //Text("Food"),
            Text("Drink"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Pastebin for food_menu_handler: [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/GFbdfcxZ)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//  Generates an 2D array of food items and places elements into cards

//  Some data
final items = ['test','test2'];
final desc = ["Loreum Isplum","Other Test"];
final price = [2.20,20.00];

//  Handles array data and puts into cards
class FoodHandler extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
              Visibility(
                visible: true,
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("COVID-19"),
                    subtitle: Text("Menu restrictions are in place"),
                  ),
                )
                  ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(items[index]),
                  subtitle: Text(desc[index]+"\n£"+price[index].toString()),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text("Add to Basket"),
                        onPressed: null,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT** I've un-nested the card (as pointed out). Hopefully this may explain what I have with explanations of what I'm trying to do

[image: what I have with explanations of what I'm trying to do]

Comment: I mean, you are actually nesting a `Card` inside a `Card`! Could you explain a bit further what you are trying to acomplish (maybe add a draw or an image)?

Comment: @MikeDedo thanks for your comments - the card has been un-nested. I've updated my original post with what I'm trying to acomplish.

Comment: I imagined you were looking for somehting like so! @ddalbosco 's answer is one of the many ways to implement it. You could also add the item when the `ListView` index is 0 and then add all your childs. You will only have to do: `itemCount: items.length + 1` (since it has one item more) and then acces the current item by `items[index - 1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the ListView.builder in a normal ListView and generate the list of its children using conditions and loops inside the list as follow:

```
//  Generates an 2D array of food items and places elements into cards

//  Some data
final items = ['test', 'test2'];
final desc = ["Loreum Isplum", "Other Test"];
final price = [2.20, 20.00];

//  Handles array data and puts into cards
class FoodHandler extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        if (1 == 1) // TODO your condition here
          Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("COVID-19"),
                    subtitle: Text("Menu restrictions are in place"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        for (int index = 0; index < items.length; index++)
          Card(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(items[index]),
                  subtitle: Text(desc[index] + "\n£" + price[index].toString()),
                ),
                ButtonBar(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Add to Basket"),
                      onPressed: null,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I marked with a TODO the line where you have to insert the condition for the first "alert".

Also I suggest you to use a class to represent the list items instead of having three different lists and "joining" them with the index, it's a more convenient and elegant solution